# Combinator pattern

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm having a little issue with the result I'm getting with 'Combinator' pattern.

```
public interface CustomerRegistrationValidator 
    extends Function<Customer, ValidationResult> {

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isEmailValid() {
        return customer -> customer.getEmail().contains("@") ? 
                    ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.EMAIL_NOT_VALID;
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isPhoneNumberValid() {
        return customer -> customer.getPhoneNumber().startsWith("+0") ?  
                    ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.PHONE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID;
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isAnAdult() {
        return customer -> Period.between(customer.getDob(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() > 16 ?  
                    ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.IS_NOT_AN_ADULT;
    }

    default CustomerRegistrationValidator and (CustomerRegistrationValidator other) {
        return customer -> {
            ValidationResult result = this.apply(customer);

            return result.equals(ValidationResult.SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
        };
    }

    enum ValidationResult {
        SUCCESS,
        PHONE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID,
        EMAIL_NOT_VALID,
        IS_NOT_AN_ADULT
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Customer customer = new Customer(
                    "Alice", 
                    "alicegmail.com", 
                    "089877878", 
                    LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1)
            );

            ValidationResult result = CustomerRegistrationValidator.isEmailValid()
                .and(CustomerRegistrationValidator.isPhoneNumberValid())
                .and(CustomerRegistrationValidator.isAnAdult())
                .apply(customer);

            System.out.println(result);

            if (result != ValidationResult.SUCCESS) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(result.name());
            }           
    }
}
```

Let's say if there are two errors from those methods(isAnAdult, isEmailValid).Why does it print only one from enum types, in my case 'EMAIL_NOT_VALID' with exception instead of two and by the second one I mean 'IS_NOT_AN_ADULT' ?

Comment: *"Why does it print only one from enum types"* Because the return value is a ***single*** enum value, i.e. the value of the first non-SUCCESS value detected. Your `and(...)` implementation specifically doesn't call the next validator when a non-SUCCESS value is detected. Given both of the above, why would you expect *multiple* validation codes?

Comment: Okay, I get your point, but I need to know exactly how many and what type of errors I'm getting.It's a bigger project and I'm doing this part and only out of curiosity I'm asking for this specific.I'm implementing something that resembles this, so it would be nice to know where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a validator to be able to return multiple *distinct* result codes (enums), then you need to change the return type to `Set<ValidationResult>`, or more specifically an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

E.g. something like this:

```
interface CustomerRegistrationValidator
    extends Function<Customer, EnumSet<ValidationResult>> {

    static final EnumSet<ValidationResult> SUCCESS_ONLY = EnumSet.of(ValidationResult.SUCCESS);

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isEmailValid() {
        return customer -> customer.getEmail().contains("@") ? 
                    SUCCESS_ONLY : EnumSet.of(ValidationResult.EMAIL_NOT_VALID);
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isPhoneNumberValid() {
        return customer -> customer.getPhoneNumber().startsWith("+0") ?  
                    SUCCESS_ONLY : EnumSet.of(ValidationResult.PHONE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID);
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isAnAdult() {
        return customer -> Period.between(customer.getDob(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() > 16 ?  
                    SUCCESS_ONLY : EnumSet.of(ValidationResult.IS_NOT_AN_ADULT);
    }

    default CustomerRegistrationValidator and(CustomerRegistrationValidator other) {
        return customer -> {
            EnumSet<ValidationResult> thisResult = this.apply(customer);
            EnumSet<ValidationResult> otherResult = other.apply(customer);
            if (thisResult.equals(SUCCESS_ONLY))
                return otherResult;
            if (otherResult.equals(SUCCESS_ONLY))
                return thisResult;
            EnumSet<ValidationResult> combinedResult = EnumSet.copyOf(thisResult);
            combinedResult.addAll(otherResult);
            return combinedResult;
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, like this.Thank you for your feedback and grasp of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In this modified code, the `CustomerRegistrationValidator` interface now returns a `List<CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult>` instead of a single `ValidationResult`. Each validator method creates an empty list of errors and adds the relevant error to the list if the validation fails.

The and method has been updated to accumulate errors from both the current validator and the other validator. It creates a new list of errors, applies the current validator (this), and adds any errors to the list. Then it applies the other validator and adds any errors from that validator as well.

Now, when you apply the validators to a customer, you will get a list of errors instead of a single error. You can then handle the errors accordingly, such as printing them or performing any other necessary actions.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface CustomerRegistrationValidator extends Function<Customer, List<CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult>> {

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isEmailValid() {
        return customer -> {
            List<CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult> errors = new ArrayList<>();
            if (!customer.getEmail().contains("@")) {
                errors.add(CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult.EMAIL_NOT_VALID);
            }
            return errors;
        };
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isPhoneNumberValid() {
        return customer -> {
            List<CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult> errors = new ArrayList<>();
            if (!customer.getPhoneNumber().startsWith("+0")) {
                errors.add(CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult.PHONE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID);
            }
            return errors;
        };
    }

    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isAnAdult() {
        return customer -> {
            List<CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult> errors = new ArrayList<>();
            if (Period.between(customer.getDob(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() <= 16) {
                errors.add(CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult.IS_NOT_AN_ADULT);
            }
            return errors;
        };
    }

    default CustomerRegistrationValidator and(CustomerRegistrationValidator other) {
        return customer -> {
            List<CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult> errors = new ArrayList<>();
            errors.addAll(this.apply(customer));
            errors.addAll(other.apply(customer));
            return errors;
        };
    }

    enum ValidationResult {
        SUCCESS,
        PHONE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID,
        EMAIL_NOT_VALID,
        IS_NOT_AN_ADULT
    }
}



Customer customer = new Customer("Alice", "alicegmail.com", "089877878", LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1));

List<CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult> errors = CustomerRegistrationValidator.isEmailValid()
        .and(CustomerRegistrationValidator.isPhoneNumberValid())
        .and(CustomerRegistrationValidator.isAnAdult())
        .apply(customer);

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    for (CustomerRegistrationValidator.ValidationResult error : errors) {
        System.out.println(error);
    }
    // Handle the errors accordingly
} else {
    // Registration is successful
}
```